# Why Windbg's dpp command output un-aligned address values

Tags: debugging, pointers, windbg

I've got a very simple program to test Windbg's dp and dpp command differences:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    i += 2;
    int& j = i;
    j += 4;
    int *pi = &i;
    *pi += 3;
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with VC2015, 32 bit debug version, and load it into Windbg for win7. I set a break point at "return 0" and observe all values:

```
0:000> dv /v
0042fd64                     argc = 0n1
0042fd68                     argv = 0x0067e0d8
0042fd24                       d2 = class DerivedTwo
0042fd54                        i = 0n9
0042fd48                        j = 0x0042fd54
0042fd3c                       pi = 0x0042fd54
0042fd30                       d1 = class DerivedOne

0:000> dp 0042fd54
0042fd54  00000009 cccccccc 0042fd70 0016214e
0042fd64  00000001 0067e0d8 0067b3e0 0042fdc8
0042fd74  00161fb0 d50638fc 00000000 00000000
0042fd84  7efde000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0042fd94  00000000 7752299d 00000000 5c35a008
0042fda4  001696ec 001696f8 000034fa 0042fd78
0042fdb4  8933efa7 0042fe14 00163b50 d5524414
0042fdc4  00000000 0042fdd0 00161e4d 0042fdd8
```

No problem, it shows that "pi" points to "i" with address of 0042fd54, so I tried to use "dpp" to see if windbg interpret pointer type correctly:

```
0:000> dpp 0042fd54
0042fd54  00000009
0042fd58  cccccccc
0042fd5c  0042fd70 0042fdc8
0042fd60  0016214e 5d0cc483
0042fd64  00000001
0042fd68  0067e0d8 0067e0e0
0042fd6c  0067b3e0 0067ef18
0042fd70  0042fdc8 0042fdd0
0042fd74  00161fb0 e8d44589
0042fd78  d50638fc
0042fd7c  00000000
0042fd80  00000000
... ...
```

> Well, my question is, when "dpp" command prints out, why some lines prints out 1  dword value, sometimes 2 dword values.

Is there any indication of how "dpp" really works and prints?

Comment: What did you expect to be printed for 00000009 and cccccccc? The contents of the memory cannot be printed if the address is not accessible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dpp` shows starts at the address given and prints the following:

- column 1: address, beginning at the start address, increasing in sizes of a pointer (4 on 32 bit, 8 on 64 bit)
- column 2: content of the memory at that addess, also in pointer sizes (like `dp <address> L1`)
- column 3: if the content of that address is a valid address again, interpret it as an address and show the content of that address again. If it's not a valid address, show nothing (unlike `dp <invalid address> L1` which would show `????????`)

When I find commands that I do not fully understand from WinDbg's help, I visualize the results like the following. This would at least have helped to figure out the meaning of the first two columns.

[image: dpp visualized]

Comment: That's a great answer. Thank you so much.